# How should I break the loop in this problem?

Tags: python

The problem:

We have to create a game, where a user inputs the number of pencils they want to use.
Expand your program by creating a loop. Each player takes turns removing pencils until 0 pencils remain on the table. Each iteration prints 2 lines: lines with pencils (vertical bars) and whose turn is now by printing the *NameX*'s turn substring.

```
How many pencils would you like to use:
> 5
Who will be the first (John, Jack):
> John
|||||
John's turn:
> 2
|||
Jack's turn:
> 1
||
John's turn:
> 2
```

**My solution:**

```
person = input("Who will be the first (John, Jack):")
print("|" * number_of_pencil)
print(f"{person}'s turn")

while number_of_pencil > 1:
    pencil = int(input())
    number_of_pencil -= pencil
    print("|" * number_of_pencil)
    if person == "John":
        print("Jack's turn")
        person = "Jack"
    else:
        print("John's turn")
        person = "John"
```

**The output:**

```
Who will be the first (John, Jack):> John
|||||
John's turn
> 2
|||
Jack's turn
> 1
||
John's turn
> 2

Jack's turn
```

**Suggestion required:** How should I break the loop?

Comment: The loop will terminate when *number_of_pencil* is less than 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
number_of_pencil = int(input("How many pencils would you like to use: "))
person = input("Who will be the first (John, Jack): ")
print("|" * number_of_pencil)

while number_of_pencil > 1:
    if person == "John":
        print("John's turn")
        person = "Jack"
    else:
        print("Jack's turn")
        person = "John"
    pencil = int(input())
    number_of_pencil -= pencil
    if number_of_pencil > 0:
      print("|" * number_of_pencil)
```

Sample:

```
How many pencils would you like to use: 5
Who will be the first (John, Jack): John
|||||
John's turn
2
|||
Jack's turn
1
||
John's turn
2
```

Instead of having the print statements indicating whether or not it is John or Jack's turn at the end of the loop, we can move them to the beginning so they will only run when there are remaining pencils.

Additionally, we will only print the number of pencils remaining if there are pencils left.

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you have any questions!